# how to predict values by using inverse square law using matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have some values from wifi routers for a floor. Now i am trying to interpolate those values using inverse square law to predict some values at some known points and want to compare with obtained values and real value. 
I am using Matlab, how i can write function.?

Comment: So you have a matrix of cartesian coordinates? Is it 2D? 3D?

Comment: i am considering x,y  for range of 1 to 100

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single router, and the signal falls of at a rate of `c/||r||^2`, where c is some constant and r is vector in 2D or 3D space representing the distance to the router, then you can create a simple inline function to calculate that...

```
f = @(r) c ./ norm(r)^2
```

If you have the x,y,z components of the distance, the function looks like

```
f = @(x,y,z) c ./ (x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2)
```

If you have a 2D or 3D matrix of values, then use

```
f = @(r) c ./ sum(r.^2); % if r = 2xn or 3xn
f = @(r) c ./ sum(r.^2,2); % if r = nx2 or nx3
```

Finally, if you only have the position r of the object and position r0 of the router, then you would use one of the following

```
% If router position is fixed for all test points...
f = @(x,y,z) c ./ ((x-x0).^2 + (y-y0).^2 + (z-z0).^2)

% If you want to test multiple router positions...
f = @(x,y,z,x0,y0,z0) c ./ ((x-x0).^2 + (y-y0).^2 + (z-z0).^2)
```

Comment: i have multiple routers with some known other reference point. and then want to calculate values to be predicted.

Comment: Well the above is a template to do that. I do not know exactly what formula you are trying to use.

Comment: i am trying to put F=power/r^2

Comment: Yes I understand that. But how do you want to handle multiple routers?

Comment: lets say that i have 5 routers with known x,y coordinates and they are emitting some power :say 1dB and so on. know another i have marked some reference points which lies after every 2 m with known x,y position. know i want to calculate the power if i go anywhere in that floor and can get rssi values from router. after that i want to check the truth value and predicted value.

Comment: And what is the equation you want to use? Are the powers cumulative? or do you want to know the strength of the best router for a given location? You have not given an implementable equation.

Comment: sir is it possible we have discussion on g talk, i can not do lots of comments in here..

Comment: yes, i want to know the strength of the best router for a given location. i dont have good idea what equation i should use. please suggest ..

Comment: Then put one of the equations above in a loop and find the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to interpolate, meaning that all your query points lie within the convex hull of your sampled points, I'd suggest using `scatteredInterpolant` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html. Its use and visualization is very easy.

```
%%Create 10 random points as example
x=rand(10,1)*100;
y=rand(10,1)*100;
strenght=rand(10,1)*100;

%% Use these data to create an interpolant function
foo=scatteredInterpolant(x,y,strenght,'natural','none');
```

At this point the function `foo` will interpolate any value within the interpolable area as `foo(x,y)`

```
foo(50,50)
%% ans = 24.6063
```

It is possible to visualize this function by plotting is as a surface

```
foos=@(a,b) foo(a,b)   %% Auxiliar function
ezsurf(foos,[0 100 0 100])    %% Plot the function
hold on
scatter3(x,y,strenght,'ro','filled') %% Add original points to see how it was calculated
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. i want to ask one thing: why we are using auxiliary function, why it is important here.?

Comment: Just to help plotting, `ezsurf` cannot handle `scatteredInterpolant` type functions. But it is not needed to query points, using `foo` directly is enough